# Sum last 24 rows Divide by 24 = NaN number

Tags: javascript

I need to Calculate the signalPower of the last 24 Hours, i connect to
an api get there my Datas which i save into my Array in PHP (also in
MySql) i send my PHP Array to JavaScript.

In JavaScript i sort my Array

```
Monday/Thuesday/Wednesday/Thursday/Friday/Saturday/Sunday
```

Pls see my Code Sorting after Weekdays: data = my Array from PHP

```
function testfunction(data) {

    let {gateway1, gateway2, gateway3, gateway4} = data;

    let result = [
        [], //0 Sunday
        [], //1 Monday
        [], //2 Tuesday
        [], //3 Wednesday
        [], //4 Thursday
        [], //5 Friday
        []  //6 Saturday
    ];

    function sort(dataset, result) {
        dataset.forEach(row => {
            row.forEach(innerRow => {
               let currentDay = moment(innerRow[11], 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
               result[currentDay.day()].push(innerRow);
            })
        });
        return result;
    }

    let resultGW1 = sort(gateway1, result);
    let resultGW2 = sort(gateway2, result);
    let resultGW3 = sort(gateway3, result);
    let resultGW4 = sort(gateway4, result);
```

After Sorting my Datas after Weekdays i try to read my as an example
Monday datas the last 24 rows

```
    //resultGWX[DAY][ROW][COLUMN]
    var i = 0;
    while(i<24){
        var z = console.log(resultGW1[1][i][1]);
        i++;
    }
    var t = parseInt(z);

    // Console.log(t) = result is number

    console.log(t/24);
}
```

When I console.log my get following info (message) on my Browser
Console: (24)-61 i think it reads the 24 rows but outputs only the
last signalpower and didn't sum the last 24 rows and divides 24

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve]

Comment: _“and didn't sum the last 24 rows”_ - where exactly do you imagine you are summing up anything in the code you have shown us? I don’t see it anywhere.

Comment: jep that must be the problem how can i sum? can u give me an example i'm a newbie

Comment: I don't see any summing? try using an object for storing the summing up of all the data

Comment: _“how can i sum?”_ - well by initializing a variable with value 0 before the loop, and then adding the individual value of each item you are looping over to it, inside the loop …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
var z = console.log(resultGW1[1][i][1]);
```

It doesn't matter what `resultGW1[1][i][1]` is because while the value might get displayed in the console, it isn't the function return value of `console.log()`.

Whatever your `console.log()` call contains, the return value is `undefined`, which means that `z` will always be set to `undefined` by this line of code.

This then means that `t` will give a `NaN` value because you're doing `parseInt()` on `undefined`, and of course your `t/24` will subsequently fail as well.

To fix this, set `z` to `resultGW1[1][i][1]` directly, away from any `console.log()` call.

You'll also need to add the value to `z` rather than just setting `z`, otherwise `z` will just be set to the last value.

So your line should look like this:

```
z += resultGW1[1][i][1];
```

You'll want to have a `var z = 0;` before the loop to initialise the `z variable as well.